# Writing a function to catch http errors while using fetch to get data from api-endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch

```js
// github users
document.getElementById('btn3').addEventListener('click', getExternal);
// fetch from external api
function getExternal() {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
        .then(function (res) {
            console.log(res.ok); //true
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then(function (users) {
            // console.log(data);
            let output = '';
            users.forEach(user => output += `<li>${user.login}</li>`);
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

// handle fetch http errors
function handleErrors(res) {
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error(res.error);
    return res;
}
```

Output of above code in developer console

```
true
app.js:55 Error
    at handleErrors (app.js:61)
```

Also If I change my function `handleErrors`to this

```js
function handleErrors(res) {
    if (!!res.ok) throw new Error(res.error);
    return res;
}
```

*Then it works as expected*

> My question(s) are
>
> 1. What is wrong with my implementation of the function `handleErrors`
> 2. What does `!!` operator do?
> 3. Good sources to learn asynchronous programming and more specifically ajax

Comment: `if (!!res.ok) throw new Error(res.error);` That looks quite odd. If `res.ok` is true, you throw an error?

Comment: `!!` is just the `!` operator, twice.  It forces the evaluation of an expression to true or false.

Comment: @Amy got it, but the `concole.log(res.ok);` is `true` even then the `handleErrors` functions throws error, what is the issue? I cant debug it

Comment: @utsavojha95 Because if `res.ok` is true, then the first `!` makes it false, then the second one makes it true again, so it throws an error if `res.ok` is true, which doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: In the function `handleErrors` i want the if block to run if `res.ok` is `false`, so my function is correct when I use `(!res.ok)` as condition for my _if_ statement right?

Comment: @utsavojha95 That seems reasonable.

Comment: @Amy If i use `(res.ok === false)` in my if condition is it the same as using `(!res.ok)`

Comment: @utsavojha95 What do you think?

Comment: Yes it should be the same, but it isn't working when I use `(!res.ok)`, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Handel error input argument is an array not the `res` you receive in
   the first then as you are returning `res.json()`.
2. Because 1. inside the error handler `res.ok` is `undefined`, hence `!!undefined` is false.
3. GIYF

Hope that helps. ;)

Side notes:

1. If fetch fails, it would go straight to the catch function so there is no need to check `res.ok`.
2. Follow the single responsibility principle. One function should only do one thing.
   Isn't it more readable this way?

```js
function getExternal() {
    return fetch('https://api.github.com/users')
        .then(function (res) {
            return res.json();
        });
}

function modifyDOM (users) {
    let output = '';
    users.forEach(user => output += `<li>${user.login}</li>`);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
}

function run() {
    getExternal()
        .then((users) => modifyDOM(users))
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
}

// or its point free version
// function run() {
//     getExternal()
//         .then(modifyDOM)
//         .catch(console.log);
// }


run();
```

Comment: Thanks, then how do I handle http errors from the response I receive? Im new to javascript and async is confusing me

Comment: Thank you @R3ctor